# Unable to connect to Amazon RDS via Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, amazon-rds

I am new to Amazon RDS and followed [this](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/create-mysql-db/) tutorial to set up a database instance. Next, I followed [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/connecting-to-amazon-rds-databases-from-eclipse/) tutorial to connect to the database instance from eclipse. I can locate the database instance from the AWS Explorer under the Amazon RDS tab. Additionally, I am able to connect to the database instance via MySQL Workbench. When I try to connect via eclipse, I receive this error:

"Unable to connect to the database.  Make sure your password is correct and make sure you can access your database through your network and any firewalls you may be connecting through."

The error log contains the following:

```
Error-Could not connect to Amazon RDS DB: testconnect - US East (Virginia).

Warning-Error creating JDBC Connection connection to Amazon RDS DB: testconnect - US East (Virginia). (Error: Unknown database 'null')

Warning-Error creating SQL Model Connection connection to Amazon RDS DB: testconnect - US East (Virginia). (Error: Unknown database 'null')
```

Error log expanded to the console:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'null'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:978)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:870)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1659)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1206)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2234)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2265)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2064)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:790)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:395)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.createConnection(JDBCConnection.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.mysql.connection.JDBCMySQLConnectionFactory.createConnection(JDBCMySQLConnectionFactory.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.internal.core.connection.ConnectionInfoImpl.initializeJDBCConnection(ConnectionInfoImpl.java:705)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.internal.core.connection.ConnectionInfoImpl.<init>(ConnectionInfoImpl.java:690)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.internal.core.connection.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.core.SQMConnectionFactory.createConnection(SQMConnectionFactory.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.internal.core.connection.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryAdapterProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryAdapterProvider.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ManagedConnection.createConnection(ManagedConnection.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.CreateConnectionJob.run(CreateConnectionJob.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
```

Comment: Do you have eclipse and " MySQL Workbench" in the same laptop/machine ?

Comment: Yes both applications are running on the same machine

Comment: The error means you didn't specify a DB name .

Comment: The DB instance name is detected by the AWS eclipse plugin as shown in the first photo here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/connecting-to-amazon-rds-databases-from-eclipse/

Answer (score 0):

check if you have access to the RDS from the eclipse host machine. you can simply use the telnet for this. most of the time we create RDS in private zone. if it's in private zone you can use the VPN connection to connect, with proper security group  configuration.